# Print result from SQL in Python3

Tags: sql, python-3.x, printing

I would like to print out the result from a SQL table but hitting a brick wall.

Here is my code

```
# Create function question_one
def question_one():
    """
    This function will return the result for question 1:
    What are the most popular three articles of all time?
    """
    query_one = """
        SELECT articles.title, COUNT(log.id) AS views
        FROM articles, log
        WHERE log.path = CONCAT('/article', articles.slug)
        GROUP BY articles.title
        ORDER BY views DESC
        LIMIT 3;
        """
    result_one = connectDatabase(query_one)
    print('1.What are the most popular three articles of all time?')
    for row in result_one:
        print(row[0], row[1]) 
    print(" ")  # Display line break for legibility
```

Python throws an error when I run it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: In some (all?) SQL flavors you can't use a column alias in an ORDER BY. Try `ORDER BY COUNT(log.id) DESC` instead.

Comment: Also don't use comma joins, that standard is deprecated by 25 years. Use the `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Thank you guys for your attention. It just shows the first print (which is the question) and nothing after it.

Comment: @JacobH Thank you for your comment, I tried them but it doesn't work. I am still working on it.

Comment: *Python throws an error* ... and what error is that? Also please show the *connectDatabase* method, very important to know here.

Comment: @Parfait Thank you very much for your comment. The problem is solved and I can not post the connectDatabase here (it was suggested to be deleted by mod).
Error was " 'NoneType' object is not iterable", but I found out that because of my misspelling, "/article" instead "/article/".
Thank everyone for your help.